# CUDA threads are time sliced. What does this mean?

Tags: cuda

Section B.10 of **CUDA Programming Guide** 4.1 explains that:

> [...] the number of clock cycles taken by the device to completely
>   execute the thread, [is different from] the number of clock cycles the
>   device actually spent executing thread instructions. The former number
>   is greater than the latter [...]

I understand that the first is the wall clock time for the completion of thread execution. The second time is first time minus the time the thread spent idle. The thread would be idle when its instructions need to wait for results from previous instructions (instruction dependency), or waiting for operand values from memory or waiting at a synchronization point.

The guide then goes on to say that:

> The former number is greater than the latter since threads are time
>   sliced.

What is the meaning of **time sliced** in this context? What does it mean by saying that threads are time sliced?

Note that this term does not appear anywhere else in the guide. (Forgive me if I am missing something obvious by context here, I am not a native English speaker.)

Comment: Time slicing probably refers to pipelining in this context.

Comment: I checked the 1.0 version of the CUDA Programming Guide, released in 2007, and the same wording appears there. But they must be mixing up the terms. I'm sure what they actually mean is context switching to hide latency, as you say in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Time slicing in this context refers to the fact that multiple warps are running on a multiprocessor (SM) and that the SM switches among warps as execution proceeds in order to hide latency. This is not the same as preemption in traditional CPU threading; nor is it the same as pipelining.

If you have code like this:

```
if (threadIdx.x == 0 && blockIdx.x == 0) x = clock();

// other work done by all threads

if (threadIdx.x == 0 && blockIdx.x == 0) y = clock();
```

If there is more than one warp running on the SM, then the value of `y-x` will be greater than the actual time spent executing in thread 0 (== warp 0). And that is not just because of thread 0 having to wait for results from instructions or memory accesses, it is also due to the time spent executing other warps.

The point of this statement in the programming guide is that it's tricky to use clock() to do absolute timing or latency measurements.

Answer (score 0):

When multiple threads are running and they have to share a processing unit then the way this is usually handled is that each thread is given a fixed maximum period of time to run (your timeslice) and then it gets preempted and another thread gets to run for a period of time. So if your thread cannot finish its work in one timeslice then it might have to wait until it is its turn again. How long that is depends on the number of parallel threads, what they are doing, how the scheduler is implemented and which processing resources are available.

Answer (score -1):

Time Slicing in this context also means [preemption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preemption_%28computing%29#Time_slice).

You can think of a time slice as being some percentage of the total available execution time.

Effectively your thread is scheduled to run for some period of time, however the scheduler may only give you a smaller time slice if other threads need to be executed.

Comment: Are you really suggesting that the *CUDA* (so NVIDIA GPU SM) scheduler includes preemption? Can you provide a link or a source confirming this?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with CUDA in detail, I was answering from a more general purpose basis. However, reading [OpenCL Programming Guide (PDF)](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/OpenCL/doc/OpenCL_Programming_Guide.pdf) Section 3.2.3, Page 27 seems to indicate so.

Comment: Perhaps pre-emption isn't technically the correct word for what CUDA's warp schedulers are doing there, but it is some kind of task switching.